# Stream video to rtmp server in Xamarin.Forms.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am currently working on a solution where i want to livestream from my app. I succesfully get my camerastream working with avfoundation. The next step in order to complete my task is to send my video frames to a rtmp server but I am not sure on how i can accomplish this in xamarin forms ios.

For swift there is a library called https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore that solves this but do we have something similiar in xamarin (any library) or documentation on examples that tackles this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late for you, but this can probably help someone who wants to do the same thing (like I did), you can use the Xamarin port of LFLiveKit:

https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-LFLiveKit

You'll have to implement a custom renderer to use it with forms, but it's not too hard if you follow the sample project in the repository.